# Angular HttpClient authorization header created but disappearing

Tags: angular, delphi, ionic-framework, http-headers, authorization

### Problem

I am trying to send Request Headers, specifically, an authorization header.
The authorization Header should look something like this:
`Authorization: Basic NTY2MTI0Og==` In a list of headers.
Where `Basic` indicates that it is encoded with base64.

I'm positive it does get added to the get request made in Angular:
[image: Request in Angular]

Although I'm not sure what `op` is.

This is what it should look like(from the standard Datasnap Delphi project):

[image: From the standard Datasnap Delphi project]

This is what mine look like:

[image: This is what mine look like]

As you can see, the Authorization header is missing.

**Errors**

Console Error:
[image: Console Error:]

Fiddler Raw request:
[image: Fiddler Raw request]

This is how I create the Rest call:

```
public authRestCall(auth: string): Observable<string> {
  var headers = new HttpHeaders;
  //HttpHeaders is immutable
  headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + auth);
  return this.http.get<string>(this.localUrl + 'DSAdmin/GetPlatformName', {headers: headers});
}
```

---

### Alternative

another way I tried doing this was to create an object like this, described in the [Angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers)

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Authorization': 'NTY2MTI0OnVuZGVmaW5lZA=='
  })
};
```

which I would then add like this:

```
return this.http.get<string>(this.localUrl + 'DSAdmin/GetPlatformName', httpOptions;
```

---

### Delphi

In the backend server (A Delphi datasnap module) I have configured CORS like this:

```
Response.setCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','*');
Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*');
```

---

### Versions

`- Angular 5

- ionic-angular: 3.9.2
- List item
- Delphi RAD studio 10.1 Berlin`

---

### Sources that did not solve it for me

[Angular 4.3 HTTPClient Basic Authorization not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894628/angular-4-3-httpclient-basic-authorization-not-working)

[Angular HttpClient not setting Authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49367195/angular-httpclient-not-setting-authorization-header)

[Angular 4.3 HttpClient doesn't send Authorization header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901160/angular-4-3-httpclient-doesnt-send-authorization-header)

[Adding “Authorization” header in get request](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/adding-authorization-header-in-get-request/91222)

I have checked many more questions, but none of them helped me solve the problem. I've been stuck on this for almost a week now. Maybe I'm not understanding something correctly, but it is not working.

If something is not clear or if I should add more info about something, please let me know.
Thank you for reading.

---

### Screenshosts as text

Angular headers object:

```
headers: Map(0) {}
lazyInit: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: 
Map(0)}
lazyUpdate: Array(1)
  0:
    name: "Authorization"
    op: "a"
    value: "Basic NTY2MTI0OnVuZGVmaW5lZA=="
    __proto__: Object
    length: 1
  __proto__: Array(0)
normalizedNames: Map(0) {}
__proto__: Object
```

What it should look like:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/DSAdmin/GetPlatformName/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8888
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2018 10:09:38 GMT
Pragma: dssession=63572.937476.131783,dssessionexpires=1197188
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,nl-NL;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Authorization: Basic NTY2MTI0Og==
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Host: localhost:8080
If-Modified-Since: Mon, 1 Oct 1990 05:00:00 GMT
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
```

What mine looks like:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/DSAdmin/GetPlatformName
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: close
Content-Length: 49
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2018 13:47:12 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="REST"
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,nl-NL;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:8100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
```

Console error:

```
VM1038:1 OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/DSAdmin/GetPlatformName 
401 (Unauthorized)
(anonymous) @ VM1038:1

(index):1 Failed to load 
http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/DSAdmin/GetPlatformName: Response for 
preflight does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Fiddler Raw:
Request

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/datasnap/rest/DSAdmin/GetPlatformName HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:8100
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,x-authentication,x-authentication-impersonate
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,nl-NL;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 49
Date: Thu, 18 Oct 2018 10:06:24 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="REST"
<HTML><BODY><B>401 Unauthorized</B></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Please post your screenshots of text as text, not as images.

Comment: @trichetriche I've done that as much as possible, problem is that the screenshots I posted will loose their structure if I create them as text, also I think it would make the question very long. Do you still think I should do this?

Comment: Yes you should : put 4 spaces in front of a line of text to make it use mono fonts, which have the same space for each character (thus keeping the formatting of the images)

Comment: As a sidenote, I'm not asking to be a pain in the ass, but because I don't have access to images hosted on image-sharing websites (such as imgur) because of the corporate proxy I'm behind (and I probably am not the only one)

Comment: I've added it. Of course you're not.

Comment: Seems like you're hitting an `OPTIONS` request first. Are you sure your CORS configuration is being used ? Also, are the `OPTIONS` requests requiring an `Authorization` header ? Because they should not !

Comment: @trichetriche I think they are being used yes, because if I do not add them, it will give me an cross origin error, which is solved by the CORS config I use at the moment.
I will check if the `OPTIONS` request requires it, I don't think so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Okay, then try deactivating the authentication on `OPTIONS` requests (`OPTIONS` requests should not be protected, as they're used to try an endpoint before sending a "real" request)

Comment: @trichetriche wow, that was actually the problem. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project !

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by adding the following piece of code to the `TWebModule1.WebModuleBeforeDispatch` in Delphi:

```
if Trim(Request.GetFieldByName('Access-Control-Request-Headers')) <> '' then
begin
  Response.SetCustomHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', Request.GetFieldByName('Access-Control-Request-Headers'));
  Handled := True;
end;
```

Source: [CORS issue on a Delphi's Datasnap ISAPI Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38786004/cors-issue-on-a-delphis-datasnap-isapi-module)